# Rails custom validation to ensure a Store always has an Owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Logically, I'm trying to demote the a `Member` role from `Owner` to `User`. Expected behaviour is to produce an error "Store must have at least one owner".

It's use-case is to support the promotion of other members roles to Owner permissions, but never leave the store without at least one owner. I thought to add a validation to the Member for that, but it appears that isn't sufficient as it let's an Owner get demoted to a User (leaving the store without an Owner). Moreover, a new Owner cannot be set after since `store_has_owner` will return false.

```
class Admin::MembersController < Admin::BaseController
  def make_user
    member = current_company.members.find(params[:id])
    if member.update(role: "user")
      redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: "#{member.user.email} is now a user."
    else
      redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, alert: member.errors
    end
  end
end
```

```
Member Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."store_id" = $1 AND "members"."role" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["store_id", 1], ["role", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:15:12 web.1      |   ↳ app/models/member.rb:21:in `store_has_owner'
15:15:12 web.1      |   Member Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "members" SET "role" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "members"."id" = $3  [["role", 1], ["updated_at", "2019-08-26 19:15:12.965431"], ["id", 1]]
15:15:12 web.1      |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/members_controller.rb:39:in `make_user'
15:15:12 web.1      |    (0.6ms)  COMMIT
15:15:12 web.1      |   ↳ app/controllers/admin/members_controller.rb:39:in `make_user'
15:15:12 web.1      | Redirected to http://lvh.me:5000/admin/dashboard
15:15:12 web.1      | Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms | Allocations: 9037)
```

Store

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
end
```

Member

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :user
  enum role: [ :owner, :user ]

  validate   :store_has_owner

  def owner?
    self.role == "owner"
  end

  def store_has_owner
    errors.add(:member, "Store must have at least one owner.") unless store.members.owner.exists?
  end
end
```

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Automatically remove the associated `members` join records
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stores, through: :members
end
```

Comment: If a store has many members, how and when do you validate that that store must have at least one owner? Don't you think their relationships aren't well defined?

Comment: @SebastianPalma care to explain more? I want to validate on the `make_user` request (which is an update method as far as custom validations go). A User can sign up and create a Store. In the StoreController create action, a Member is made for that Store with an Owner role. Now, as the owner of a Store, I can invite other team members as Users - even promote them to Owners. However, you should not be able to call `make_user` if it'll leave the Store without an Owner

Comment: Would `self.errors.add(:base,...)` work? I'm new to adding errors and all, but I've only seen them added to the base if it's adding to self

Comment: I issue isn't getting the error to display it's the logic being executed. If a user is the owner of the store, they shouldn't be able to demote themselves to a user role - however, the above `unless store.members.owner.exists?` isn't sufficient.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this helps `store.members.any? { |m| (m == self ? self : m).owner? }`

Comment: Thanks @LyzardKyng - this works. Could you elaborate what is happening in the block? Or is there another way to interpret it? Also, as a full answer so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unless` clause should be

```rb
store.members.any? { |m| (m == self ? self : m).owner? }
```

There we're finding *any* member (`m`) in the `members` collection which `owner?` method returns `true`, i.e. Store has at least one Owner.

There is one caveat though. Accessing `store.members` causes selecting this relation from database and, because changed role of `self` is uncommitted yet, it returns that `self` is an Owner and this check don't work as expected. To avoid this we substitute `m` with `self` when they are equal, so `m.owner?` became `self.owner?` and returns `false` as expected.

Comment: `>  because changed role of self is uncommitted yet, it returns that self is an Owner and this check don't work as expected`

Thanks for understanding this part @LyzardKyng - as shown in my trace this was the caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions I can think of:

1) This validation does not belongs to the member, but to the store. The store cannot be valid without an owner. Move it to the store and then add `validates_associated :store` to `user.rb`.

```
#store.rb
validate :has_owner

def has_owner
  errors.add(:base, "Store must have at least one owner.") unless members.owner.any?
end
```

This should take care of the problem and is cleaner. Another solution follows. A bit dirtier but...

2) You can deal with this in the workflow of reducing a `Member` from `Owner` to `User`, by making sure there is another owner other than the member you are demoting. So:

```
# admin/members_controller.rb
def make_user
  member = current_company.members.find(params[:id])
  if member.update(role: "user") && current_company.has_other_owner_than(member)?
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: "#{member.user.email} is now a user."
  else
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, alert: member.errors
  end
end

# store.rb
def has_other_owner_than?(member)
  members.where(role: :owner).not(id: member.id).any? # Rails 5
  # or
  # members.where("role = ? AND id != ?", Member.roles[:owner], member.id).any? # Rails 4.2
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response Tashows. I just tried to implement both solutions. Could you help me understand how the first solution is more valid? When the `make_user` action is called, it validates `store_has_owner`. This will return true since there is an owner, and then proceed to demote the owner to a user. I left the trace below.

Comment: ↳ app/controllers/admin/members_controller.rb:43:in `make_user'
Member Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."store_id" = $1 AND "members"."role" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["store_id", 1], ["role", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/models/store.rb:61:in `store_has_owner'
Member Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "members" SET "role" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "members"."id" = $3  [["role", 1], ["updated_at", "2019-08-30 01:44:00.194024"], ["id", 1]]
COMMIT